# Spline curevature in python using splprep and splev

Tags: python, spline

I'm trying to evaluate the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#:%7E:text=where%20primes%20refer%20to%20derivatives%20with%20respect%20to%20t.%20The%20curvature%20%CE%BA%20is%20thus) of a spline: [equation for K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEA0z.png)

I'm using Python3.8.
The spline was generated using [splprep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html). I cannot use other functions (splrep, bspline, cubic_spline,...) because my data cannot be represented as y=f(x), and in the future I will have 3D curvature.

I tried to calculate it this way:

```
def spline_curvature(self, tck):
    u_new = np.linspace(0, 1, int(1e7))
    # x, y = interpolate.splev(u_new, tck)
    dx, dy = interpolate.splev(u_new, tck, der=1)
    ddx, ddy = interpolate.splev(u_new, tck, der=2)
    K = abs(dx * ddy - dy * ddx) / ((dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** (3 / 2))
    return K
```

When generating the spline I used a very discrete 'u' parameter (1,1e7)
In the next figure you can see the spline:
[spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sojFo.png)

In the next figure, you can see the curvature parameter along the spline. the x-axis is u parameter, the y-axis is the K (curvature) value.
[curvature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHFJR.png)

For some reason, the K parameter is very noisy and does not make sense.
For example the"testing points" the spline seems to be "smooth" but the curvature is about K=1.7, meaning the radius is R=1/K=0.59.
[testing points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7S8X.png), [curvature tesing points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH6wD.png)

I assume this is because 'splev' calculates the derivative numerically, rather than analyticly?

```
interpolate.splev(u_new, tck, der=1)
interpolate.splev(u_new, tck, der=2)
```

Any ideas on how can I calculate the curvature of a spline?

Comment: How do you generate `tck` exactly ?

Comment: the spline was generated with this function:
"            tck, u = interpolate.splprep([path_x, path_y], s=0, k=3)"
I tried different values of 's' smoothing parameter, starting from 0 to 646 which is the number of datapoints in 'path_x' as suggested in the documentation.

Comment: `tck, u = interpolate.splprep([path_x, path_y], s=0, k=3)`

Comment: I've been doing a few tests and it seems to me that your formulation is correct, and on the test cases I used gave me the correct curvature (and radius). Did you check that `x, y = interpolate.splev(u_new, tck)` does match your input curve ?

Comment: Yes. The spline is pretty close to the original curve.

I tested the equation also. I wrote an analytic equation `Asin(at)+Bcos(bt)`.
Computed the analytic curvature. Then calculated the curvature using the showed equation and using spline. The results were identical.

That why I can't figure why in the case I showed in the post re curvature is noisy.

Comment: Is it still noisy when using less points than `1e7` for `u`? `1e7` seems like quite a step up from 646 points in the dataset.